# Using ZeroClipboard on a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, zeroclipboard

I have a Twitter Bootstrap modal that I am displaying where I want to include a "Copy to Clipboard" button.  I am attempting to use the ZeroClipboard component https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard

Below is my sample code.  Button "Copy1" is on a page directly and that works.  Button "Copy2" is on the modal and that is not working.  Internet Explorer appears to "lock up" when "Copy2" is pressed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <!-- Textbox and copy button pair #1 (not on modal) -->
            <input type="text" id="Input1" />
            <button class="btn" type="button" id="Copy1" data-clipboard-target="Input1">Copy Input #1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <a class="btn" type="button" href="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal">Show Modal Dialog</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" id="Modal1">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3>Copy to Clipboard Modal</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                <!-- Textbox and copy button pair #2 (on modal) -->
                <input type="text" id="Input2" />
                <button class="btn" type="button" id="Copy2" data-clipboard-target="Input2">Copy Input #2</button>
            </p>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <p>
                <button class="btn" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            ZeroClipboard.setDefaults({
                moviePath: '/Scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf'
            });

            var clip1 = new ZeroClipboard($("#Copy1"));
            var clip2 = new ZeroClipboard($("#Copy2"));
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone offer some guidance on what is going wrong?  I understand that Bootstrap takes the modal out of the DOM tree until displayed, but I'm not sure how to accommodate for that.

**Edit:** Corrected id of 2nd input to be "Input2" to match the button's target.

In addition, I have attempted the following javascript:

```js
//var clip2 = new ZeroClipboard($("#Copy2"));
$("#Modal1").on('shown', function () {
  var clip2 = new ZeroClipboard($("#Copy2"));
});
```

Also, it would appear that the issue is browser-specific.

The original code and my modified code locks up Internet Explorer 10.  But Google Chrome is OK under both code attempts.

Comment: see: https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard/issues/90

Comment: If I remove the ZeroClipboard that works, then the one on the modal still does not work.

Comment: @Bass: That issue is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd copy button is targeting a nonexistent ID:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" id="Copy2" data-clipboard-target="Input2">Copy Input #2</button>
```

Your markup is incorrect:

```
<input type="text" id="Text2" />
```

Should be:

```
<input type="text" id="Input2" />
```

Comment: I have corrected the HTML in my original question.  I have also added some more information.  It would appear my issue is IE-specific.

Answer (score 0):

When we use "ZeroClipboard" with "Bootstrap modal", it creates conflict in "IE".

We need to make changes in bootstrap's "js" file.

There is method defined for, “ Modal.prototype.enforceFocus “ element in “Bootstrap.js” .

Here, in “If” condition, we need to add following condition,

```
!$(e.target).closest('[id ^= "ZeroClipboardMovie_"]').length)
```

Resultant code will look as follows,

```
if (this.$element[0] !== e.target && !this.$element.has(e.target).length && !$(e.target).closest('[id ^= "ZeroClipboardMovie_"]').length) {
         this.$element.focus()
 }
```

where, [id ^= "ZeroClipboardMovie_"] is ZeroClipboard container element.

In above code, it is taking container of recent "ZeroClipboard". You can change it to, appropriate "zeroclipboard-container" as per the requirement.

You can also checkout this blog post for more detail- http://wisdmlabs.com/blog/ie-issue-zeroclipboard-bootstrap-modal/

Answer (score 0):

```js
  if (!checkIsBelowIE8()) {
                if (/MSIE|Trident/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
                    (function ($) {
                        var zcClass = '.' + ZeroClipboard.config('containerClass');
                        var proto = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype;
                        proto.enforceFocus = function () {
                            $(document)
                        .off('focusin.bs.modal')  /* Guard against infinite focus loop */
                        .on('focusin.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
                            if (this.$element[0] !== e.target &&
                             !this.$element.has(e.target).length &&
                            /* Adding this final condition check is the only real change */
                             !$(e.target).closest(zcClass).length
                          ) {
                                this.$element.focus();
                            }
                        }, this));
                        };
                    })(window.jQuery);
                }
                var client = new ZeroClipboard($(".clipboard"));
                client.on("copy", function (e) {
                    var clipboard = e.clipboardData;
                    clipboard.setData("text/plain", $.trim($(e.target).parent().prev().find("input").val()));
                    showMsg("success", "copy success");
                });
            }
function checkIsBelowIE8() {
    try {
        var b_name = navigator.appName;
        var b_version = navigator.appVersion;
        var version = b_version.split(";");
        var trim_version = version[1].replace(/[ ]/g, "");
        if (b_name == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            /*if IE6 or IE7*/
            if (trim_version == "MSIE8.0" || trim_version == "MSIE7.0" || trim_version == "MSIE6.0") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

hope to help you